# Triple integral for a pyramid (calculating volume)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Fix $H>0$ and let $P\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the solid pyramid with vertices at $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,2,0),(0,2,0)$ and $(0,0,H)$. Calculate the volume $V_P$ of $P$.**

I know that I must set up a triple integral to solve this problem, but I'm unsure of how to set this up as I have never done this before. How do I create the limits of the integrals and how do I set up the function within the integral?

Comment: Hint: the volume of a solid $S$ in space is $\iiint_S dV$. Find the equation of the planes that makes the faces of the pyramid. To gain insight, start with a very simple tetrahedron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base of the pyramid in $XY$ plane has vertices $O(0,0,0), A(1,0,0), B(1,2,0)$ and $C(0,2,0)$. The top of the pyramid is at $P(0, 0, h)$ [just an observation: this is a pyramid where top of the pyramid is not centered, rather it is above one of the corners].

The integral itself is straightforward. The bounds of $x$ is between $0$ and plane going through $ABP$ and the bounds of $y$ is between $0$ and plane going through $BCP$. While bound of $z$ is $0 \leq z \leq h$.

We know the general equation of the plane is $ax+by+cz=d$.

Now take the plane going through $A, B$ and $P$. It is parallel to $y$ axis and hence the plane will be of the form $ax+cz=d$. Plug in coordinates of $A$ and $P$ in the equation and you get the equation of plane as $\displaystyle x + \frac{z}{h} = 1$.

Similarly equation of plane going through $B, C$ and $P$ is parallel to $x$ axis and plugging in coordinates of points, the equation of plane is $\displaystyle y + \frac{2z}{h} = 2$.

So we finally come to the following bounds -

$0 \leq x \leq \displaystyle 1 - \frac{z}{h}$;
$0 \leq y \leq \displaystyle 2 - \frac{2z}{h}$; $0 \leq z \leq h$.

Order of integration is $dx \ dy$ (or $dy \ dx$) and $dz$ last.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using two integrals, one for each triangular prism. Begin by drawing the xy plane and the four points of the base, as well as a diagonal from $(1,2)$ to $(0,0)$. For the lower right triangle, the plane formed by the side of the pyramid contains vectors $(0,0,H)-(1,0,0)=(-1,0,H)$ and $(0,0,H)-(1,2,0)=(-1,-2,H)$. Take the cross product to get $(2H, 0, 2)$, a normal vector to the plane. The equation of the plane can be found by the dot product $(2H, 0, 2) \cdot (x-0, y-0, z-H)=0$, giving $z=H(1-x)$. Then the limits of integration are $0<z<H(1-x), y/2<x<1, and 0<y<2$.

For the other half, the same thing happens. Find two vectors in the plane, they can be $(0,0,H)-(0,2,0)=(0,-2,H)$ and $(0,0,H)-(1,2,0)=(-1,-2,H)$ with a cross product of $(0, H, 2)$. Thus an equation of the plane is $(0,H,2)\cdot (x-0,y-0,z-H)=0$ giving us $z=H(1-y/2)$. The limits of integration are therefore $0<z<H\left(1-\frac y2\right),0<x<\frac y 2,0<y<2$.

The volume of the pyramid is given by $$\int_0^2\int_{\frac y 2}^1\int_0^{H(1-x)}dzdxdy+\int_0^2\int_0^{\frac y 2}\int_0^{H\left(1-\frac y 2\right)}dzdxdy$$

It turns out that the volume of the two pieces are the same.